# Index out of bounds error that I cannot resolve

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a very simple python problem, but I fiddled around with the numbers and it still doesn't work.

```
import random
import numpy as np

class Room:
 def __init__(self, name, contents):
  self.name = name
  self.contents = contents

rooms = np.zeros((10, 10))

emptyRooms = []

halfHeight = int(len(rooms[1]) / 2)
halfWidth = int(len(rooms[0]) / 2)

rooms[halfWidth][halfHeight] = 1

for r in range(len(rooms)):
 for c in range(len(rooms)):
  if rooms[r][c] == 1:
   if rooms[r][c-1] != 1:
    rooms[r][c-1] = 1
   if rooms[r][c+1] != 1:
    rooms[r][c+1] = 1
   if rooms[r-1][c] != 1:
    rooms[r-1][c] = 1
   if rooms[r+1][c] != 1:
    rooms[r+1][c] = 1

 print(rooms)
```

And here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
  if rooms[r+1][c] != 1:
 IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10
```

Like I said, I have tried fiddles with the numbers and it still comes out to an error. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Python indexing starts with 0. Your size is 10. When your r is equal to 9 (last index), r+1 is 10 so rooms[r+1] causes an exception. In most other languages, you'd hit the same error earlier - with c-1 (c==0, c-1==-1 - but python accepts negative indexes -i as len-i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access one next element in an array using index while iterating through the array, you would need to iterate up to the second last element. Here, you are using `rooms[r][c+1]` and `rooms[r+1][c]` considering r and c as indices. While in the last iteration, your index goes out of bounds. So, here you'd need to iterate the loop to the second last index. Try the following code:

```
import random
import numpy as np

class Room:
    def __init__(self, name, contents):
        self.name = name
        self.contents = contents

rooms = np.zeros((10, 10))

emptyRooms = []

halfHeight = int(len(rooms[1]) / 2)
halfWidth = int(len(rooms[0]) / 2)

rooms[halfWidth][halfHeight] = 1

for r in range(len(rooms) - 1):
    for c in range(len(rooms) - 1):
        if rooms[r][c] == 1:
            if rooms[r][c-1] != 1:
                rooms[r][c-1] = 1
            if rooms[r][c+1] != 1:
                rooms[r][c+1] = 1
            if rooms[r-1][c] != 1:
                rooms[r-1][c] = 1
            if rooms[r+1][c] != 1:
                rooms[r+1][c] = 1

print(rooms)
```

Here I'm initializing the loop up to `range(len(rooms) - 1)` instead of `range(len(rooms))`. I hope it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Wouldn't this skip the last room in both r and z axis?

Comment: Yes it won't process the last room but assuming the output of the program, it's setting all values to 1 which are greater than rooms[halfHeight][halfWidth]. The current output does the same leaving the rooms[len(rooms) - 1][len(rooms) - 1] as 0.

Comment: Depending on the goal of the program, we can adjust the code but this is how you can resolve the error, and understand it.

Comment: This should be working, but if you really want to check for the last row and column of the list, take a look at my Answer. But @Nouman Ahsan is right because nothing different is specified here.

Comment: This works percetly and it still changes values on the bottom and right! Thank you!

Comment: @jedidiahblitz should the bottom right room be a 1 or a 0?

Comment: This answer has a 0 there, mine a 1. Depending on what you want this may be desired.

Answer (score 0):

You have `c+1`, with `c` in `range(len(rooms)):` when `c` is the last one `c+1` will be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to check if r+1 or c+1 is smaller than ten, because than it tries to index an element, which does not exist *(often also called out of bounds)*.**

So in you code do:

```
import random
import numpy as np

class Room:
 def __init__(self, name, contents):
  self.name = name
  self.contents = contents

rooms = np.zeros((10, 10))

emptyRooms = []

halfHeight = int(len(rooms[1]) / 2)
halfWidth = int(len(rooms[0]) / 2)

rooms[halfWidth][halfHeight] = 1

for r in range(len(rooms)):
 for c in range(len(rooms)):
  if rooms[r][c] == 1:
   if (c-1) >= 0 and rooms[r][c-1] != 1:
    rooms[r][c-1] = 1
   if (c+1) < 10 and rooms[r][c+1] != 1:
    rooms[r][c+1] = 1
   if (r-1) >= 0 and rooms[r-1][c] != 1:
    rooms[r-1][c] = 1
   if (r+1) < 10 and rooms[r+1][c] != 1:
    rooms[r+1][c] = 1
print(rooms)
```

**To make sure that at every position where you add 1 to either c or r the resulting integer is never greater than or equal to 10 (would always result in out of Bounds Error).**

**Edit: Probably you will also not want to get wrapping results in the negative direction. So i added also a check for the negative direction. *(The Parts with '(r-1) >= 0'.)***